# NetEncoder for images of "Varying" dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convolution

I'm looking for someway to do what this syntax "should" do:

```
NetEncoder[{"Image", Automatic, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}] /@ imgs;
```

The documentation states that `NetEncoder["Image"]` is equivalent to `NetEncoder[{"Image", {128,128}}]`. But I don't want to resize the training images to a constant size (e.g. I'm training a fully convolutional network). I simply want like to encode them as 3-tensors with whatever `ImageDimensions` they actually are.

For example, say I have the following two images with dimensions `{{4608, 3456}, {512, 512}}`. Using `NetEncoder` forces us to resize both images to a fixed dimension, which is not what I want:

```
imgs = ExampleData /@ {{"TestImage", "Stall"}, {"TestImage", "F16"}};
NetDecoder["Image"]@*NetEncoder["Image"] /@ imgs
```

[image]

The documentation also states that a `ConvolutionLayer` can operate on tensors that contain "Varying" dimensions, which seems helpful:

```
imgsData = ImageData[#, Interleaving -> False] & /@ imgs;
conv = NetInitialize @ ConvolutionLayer[3, 2, "Input" -> {3, Automatic, Automatic}]
ImageAdjust@*NetDecoder["Image"]@*conv@*NetEncoder["Image"] /@ imgs
ImageAdjust@*NetDecoder["Image"]@*conv /@ imgsData
```

[image]

But then we also lose all the benefits of using a `NetEncoder` (out-of-core parallel file loading, etc..) *Is there a way around this issue?*

**Updates:**

Automatic doesn't work for dimensions in a custom encoder:

```
enc = NetEncoder[{"Function", 
   ImageData[FastImageImport@#, Interleaving -> False] &, {3, Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

not to mention importing images yourself is a terrible idea (slows down training 100x).

Here's the motivating example of a fully convolutional net one might want to train on images of varying size:

```
n = NetInitialize[NetChain[{
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Dilation" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 1],
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Dilation" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 2],
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Dilation" -> 4, "PaddingSize" -> 4], 
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Dilation" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 1],
    ConvolutionLayer[3, {1, 1}, "Dilation" -> 1]
},
"Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {"Varying", "Varying"}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}],
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]], 
Method -> "Identity"]
```

[image]

Comment: Not possible. Because the the dimension of output of convolutional net is depend on the dimension of input. If the dimension of input is varying, the number of class in the output is changed.

Comment: @partida there is no class in the output, the output is an image

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to apply any convolution to any image of any size? If I'm training on image input-output pairs, all that matters is that the input and output have the same dimensions so that the MeanSquaredLossLayer will work.

Comment: If the dimension of input and ouput is identity, it should be work. In the ref/netencoder/Image, it seems no options fotr this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Automatic` is not the same as "Varying".

**Example 1**

This works:

```
conv1 = NetInitialize@ConvolutionLayer[3, 2, "Input" -> {3, Automatic, Automatic}];
conv1@NetEncoder[{"Image", {128, 128}}]@RandomImage[1, {128, 128}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

[image]

This doesn't work at the stage of layer creation:

```
conv2 = NetInitialize@ConvolutionLayer[3, 2, "Input" -> {3, "Varying", "Varying"}]
```

[image]

**Example 2**

This doesn't work at the stage of neural network training:

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, RandomInteger[{3, 64}], 64}], {10}];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10];

net1 = NetChain[
   {
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}],
    AggregationLayer[Mean],
    2,
    SoftmaxLayer[]
    },
   "Input" -> {3, Automatic, Automatic},
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
   ];

NetTrain[net1, X -> Y]
```

[image]

This doesn't work at the stage of network creation:

```
net2 = NetChain[
   {
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}],
    AggregationLayer[Mean],
    2,
    SoftmaxLayer[]
    },
   "Input" -> {3, "Varying", "Varying"},
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
   ];
```

[image]

**Conclusions**

`ConvolutionLayer` supports "Varying" only as the first dimension and if `"Interleaving" -> True`.

```
Do[
  Print[{i, ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Interleaving" -> False, "Input" -> i]}],
  {i, Tuples[{64, "Varying"}, 3]}
  ] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
Do[
  Print[{i, ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Interleaving" -> True, "Input" -> i]}],
  {i, Tuples[{64, "Varying"}, 3]}
  ] // Quiet
```

[image]

This works:

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {RandomInteger[{3, 64}], 64, 3}], {10}];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10];

net = NetChain[
   {
    ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Interleaving" -> True],
    AggregationLayer[Mean, 1;;2],
    2,
    SoftmaxLayer[]
    },
   "Input" -> {"Varying", 64, 3},
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
   ];

NetTrain[net, X -> Y]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

As I understand, support of "Varying" dimension was added in `ConvolutionLayer` to work with text of varying size ([ConvS2S](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1978007565818999/a-novel-approach-to-neural-machine-translation/) etc.), not with images.

```
NetChain[
 {
  EmbeddingLayer[10],
  ConvolutionLayer[32, {3}, "Interleaving" -> True],
  AggregationLayer[Mean, 1],
  2,
  SoftmaxLayer[]
  },
 "Input" -> "Varying",
 "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
 ]
```

[image]

So your problem is not only in the `NetEncoder` that doesn't support varying dimensions.

Probably support of more than one "Varying" dimension will be added in the next releases.